# Trying to run an old version of RedHat

Tags: rhel, drivers, console, distribution-choice

For my PhD project, my supervisor has suggested to install this (old) mathematical software: http://www.gang.umass.edu/software/cmclab/index.html As you can see in the requirements, this software runs in Linux RedHat 7.1/7.2 i686.

I've tried to set up a virtual machine with the 7.2 version and, after the installation, the OS starts in command mode, and won't switch to desktop mode (needed to use this software). I've digged a little bit and it seems that these old versions are not able to install drivers for the "modern" hardware (or even recognize it), and therefore this system can't start in the graphic mode because it has not clue how to use the screen...

Right, so as far as I can see I have two options:

1. Try to (somehow) find and install in command mode the right drivers for my graphic card, and hope that this solves the issue. [I'd say very unlikely]
2. Try to install another distribution (maybe similar enough to enigma 7.2) in which this software can run. This looks like a decent idea, but I don't know which distribution I could pick. This is a software made by a mathematician with who I don't have contact, so I can't ask them if there is such an alternative.

Could anyone, based on the very little information provided in the software web page, help me choosing the "right" distribution? Or maybe does someone have some hope in the first option?

Comment: You need to list what the virtual machine is. Hopefully you selected virtualbox, if not, help will be difficult to give, so I'd install virtualbox first, then recreate the image if you have not used virtualbox. Virtualbox has what are called extensions, which come with the install, but you have to mount the installer cd and then run the installer from inside virtualbox. This will install the virtualbox graphics driver. Redhat 7.2 was released just a few years ago, and that should work fine. I seriously doubt it requires redhat, though it is probably an rpm package.

Comment: Note that this is just about a certain subset of dependencies your math program has, nothing else, at least that's usually the case. If it's an rpm, it's maybe easier to use an rpm distro, but mostly what will matter is the dependencies, the versions that is. Note that the extension pack is in your host system, NOT in the guest, which is why you have to mount that iso image in your guest, then run the installer there. You should also list the OS of the host, otherwise one can't give further assistance. You should also describe the package, is it an rpm, a tar.gz?

Comment: @Lizardx Edu is talking about Red Hat Linux 7.1/7.2 (Enigma) from 2001 (really 16 years ago...I'm geting old ;-) ). But I agree, setup some VM guest on your favourite virtualization solution with GPU emulation from that time (probably Cirrus) and it should work.

Comment: Oh, thanks for catching that, I forgot about that change, and that they restarted numbering with RHEL, right. That makes the question deserve an upvote, since that's a valuable solution if someone posts a clear set of steps.

Comment: I'd check first on how feasible it is to build the application anew [from source](http://www.gang.umass.edu/software/download/gangsrc-020918.tar.gz).  You'd learn more.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to change the emulated graphics hardware, but another possibility would be to leave the hardware alone and try the generic vesa driver (assuming it's available in the old redhat and you can figure out how to load it)

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for the suggestion. This would be definitely a nice solution, but looks very time consuming... Anyway, could you please maybe explain briefly what steps should I follow to recompile this software and make it available for a newer linux system?

Answer (score 2):

Hypervisors usually support several types of virtualized hardware. Make sure you have selected an old one.

Another approach is to do without the local X output:

1. You could run `ssh -X`, execute the software in the VM and view the X output on another system.
2. You can install a virtual X server which the application can connect to. You need some kind of remote access (e.g. VNC) in this case, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Framebuffers.

**Procedure:**

```
Initialise X configuration files:

1. Login root console 
2. Run "Xconfigurator"
2.1. At "Welcome", select Ok
2.2. At "Choose a Card", select "XGA-1  (ISA bus)"
2.3  At "Monitor Setup", select Custom
2.4. At "Custom Monitor Setup", select Ok
2.5. At "Custom Monitor Setup (continued)", select "Standard VGA, 640x480 @ 60 Hz"
2.6. At "Custom Monitor Setup (continued)", select "50-70 Hz"
2.7. At "Screen Configuration", select "Don't Probe"
2.8. At "Video Memory", select "1 mb" (or whatever the setting is in Virtual Box)
2.9. At "Clockchip Configuration", select "No Clockchip Setting (recommended)"
2.10. At "Probe for Clocks", select Skip
2.11. At "Select Video Modes", select only "8 bit: 640x480"
2.12. At "Starting X", select Skip
2.13. At "You're Done!", select Ok

Switch to X framebuffer driver:

1. Type "ln -sf /usr/X11R6/bin/XF86_FBDev /etc/X11/X"
2. Add a FBDev screen driver section to /etc/X11/XF86Config:

        Section "Screen"
            Driver "FBDev"
            Device "Generic VGA"
            Monitor "My Monitor"
            SubSection "Display"
                Modes "default"
            EndSubSection
        EndSection

Enable kernel framebuffer mode: 

1. vim /boot/grub/grub.conf
2. Append "vga=773" to the kernel line (8 bit 1024×768) (for other modes see "Available VGA Modes" below) eg: 

        kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.7-10 ro root=/dev/hda2 vga=773

3. Reboot

Start X GUI:

1. Login root console
2. Type "startx"

X will start in the desired video mode.
```

References:

- https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/x1232.html
- https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/grub-vga-modes.html

---

**Config files:**

XF86Config:

```
# File generated by XConfigurator.

# **********************************************************************
# Refer to the XF86Config(4/5) man page for details about the format of 
# this file.
# **********************************************************************

# **********************************************************************
# Files section.  This allows default font and rgb paths to be set
# **********************************************************************

Section "Files"

# The location of the RGB database.  Note, this is the name of the
# file minus the extension (like ".txt" or ".db").  There is normally
# no need to change the default.

    RgbPath "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/rgb"

# Multiple FontPath entries are allowed (they are concatenated together)
# By default, Red Hat 6.0 and later now use a font server independent of
# the X server to render fonts.

    FontPath   "unix/:7100"

EndSection

# **********************************************************************
# Server flags section.
# **********************************************************************

Section "ServerFlags"

    # Uncomment this to cause a core dump at the spot where a signal is 
    # received.  This may leave the console in an unusable state, but may
    # provide a better stack trace in the core dump to aid in debugging
    #NoTrapSignals

    # Uncomment this to disable the <Crtl><Alt><BS> server abort sequence
    # This allows clients to receive this key event.
    #DontZap

    # Uncomment this to disable the <Crtl><Alt><KP_+>/<KP_-> mode switching
    # sequences.  This allows clients to receive these key events.
    #DontZoom

EndSection

# **********************************************************************
# Input devices
# **********************************************************************

# **********************************************************************
# Keyboard section
# **********************************************************************

Section "Keyboard"

    Protocol    "Standard"

    # when using XQUEUE, comment out the above line, and uncomment the
    # following line
    #Protocol   "Xqueue"

    AutoRepeat  500 5

    # Let the server do the NumLock processing.  This should only be 
    # required when using pre-R6 clients
    #ServerNumLock

    # Specify which keyboard LEDs can be user-controlled (eg, with xset(1))
    #Xleds      1 2 3

    #To set the LeftAlt to Meta, RightAlt key to ModeShift, 
    #RightCtl key to Compose, and ScrollLock key to ModeLock:

    LeftAlt        Meta
    RightAlt        Meta
   ScrollLock      Compose
   RightCtl        Control

# To disable the XKEYBOARD extension, uncomment XkbDisable.

#    XkbDisable

# To customise the XKB settings to suit your keyboard, modify the
# lines below (which are the defaults).  For example, for a non-U.S.
# keyboard, you will probably want to use:
#    XkbModel    "pc102"
# If you have a US Microsoft Natural keyboard, you can use:
#    XkbModel    "microsoft"
#
# Then to change the language, change the Layout setting.
# For example, a german layout can be obtained with:
#    XkbLayout   "de"
# or:
#    XkbLayout   "de"
#    XkbVariant  "nodeadkeys"
#
# If you'd like to switch the positions of your capslock and
# control keys, use:
#    XkbOptions  "ctrl:swapcaps"

# These are the default XKB settings for XFree86
#    XkbRules    "xfree86"
#    XkbModel    "pc101"
#    XkbLayout   "us"
#    XkbVariant  ""
#    XkbOptions  ""

   XkbKeycodes     "xfree86"
   XkbTypes        "default"
   XkbCompat       "default"
   XkbSymbols      "us(pc101)"
   XkbGeometry     "pc"
   XkbRules        "xfree86"
    XkbModel        "pc101"
    XkbLayout       "us"
EndSection

# **********************************************************************
# Pointer section
# **********************************************************************

Section "Pointer"
    Protocol    "PS/2"
    Device      "/dev/mouse"
    ZAxisMapping 4 5

# When using XQUEUE, comment out the above two lines, and uncomment
# the following line.

#    Protocol   "Xqueue"

# Baudrate and SampleRate are only for some Logitech mice

#    BaudRate   9600
#    SampleRate 150

# Emulate3Buttons is an option for 2-button Microsoft mice
# Emulate3Timeout is the timeout in milliseconds (default is 50ms)

#    Emulate3Buttons
#    Emulate3Timeout    50

# ChordMiddle is an option for some 3-button Logitech mice

#    ChordMiddle

EndSection


# **********************************************************************
# Monitor section
# **********************************************************************

# Any number of monitor sections may be present

Section "Monitor"

    Identifier  "My Monitor"
    VendorName  "Unknown"
    ModelName   "Unknown"

# HorizSync is in kHz unless units are specified.
# HorizSync may be a comma separated list of discrete values, or a
# comma separated list of ranges of values.
# NOTE: THE VALUES HERE ARE EXAMPLES ONLY.  REFER TO YOUR MONITOR'S
# USER MANUAL FOR THE CORRECT NUMBERS.

    HorizSync   31.5

# VertRefresh is in Hz unless units are specified.
# VertRefresh may be a comma separated list of discrete values, or a
# comma separated list of ranges of values.
# NOTE: THE VALUES HERE ARE EXAMPLES ONLY.  REFER TO YOUR MONITOR'S
# USER MANUAL FOR THE CORRECT NUMBERS.

    VertRefresh 50-70

# Modes can be specified in two formats.  A compact one-line format, or
# a multi-line format.

# These two are equivalent

#    ModeLine "1024x768i" 45 1024 1048 1208 1264 768 776 784 817 Interlace

#    Mode "1024x768i"
#        DotClock   45
#        HTimings   1024 1048 1208 1264
#        VTimings   768 776 784 817
#        Flags      "Interlace"
#    EndMode

# This is a set of standard mode timings. Modes that are out of monitor spec
# are automatically deleted by the server (provided the HorizSync and
# VertRefresh lines are correct), so there's no immediate need to
# delete mode timings (unless particular mode timings don't work on your
# monitor). With these modes, the best standard mode that your monitor
# and video card can support for a given resolution is automatically
# used.

# 512x384 @ 78 Hz, 31.50 kHz hsync
Modeline "512x384"    20.160 512  528  592  640   384  385  388  404 -HSync -VSync
# 512x384 @ 85 Hz, 34.38 kHz hsync
Modeline "512x384"    22     512  528  592  640   384  385  388  404 -HSync -VSync

# 640x400 @ 70 Hz, 31.5 kHz hsync
Modeline "640x400"     25.175 640  664  760  800   400  409  411  450
# 640x400 @ 85 Hz, 37.86 kHz hsync
Modeline "640x400"     31.5   640  672 736   832   400  401  404  445 -HSync +VSync

# 640x480 @ 100 Hz, 53.01 kHz hsync
Modeline "640x480"     45.8   640  672  768  864   480  488  494  530 -HSync -VSync
# 640x480 @ 60 Hz, 31.5 kHz hsync
Modeline "640x480"     25.175 640  664  760  800   480  491  493  525
# 640x480 @ 72 Hz, 36.5 kHz hsync
Modeline "640x480"     31.5   640  680  720  864   480  488  491  521
# 640x480 @ 75 Hz, 37.50 kHz hsync
ModeLine  "640x480"    31.5   640  656  720  840   480  481  484  500 -HSync -VSync
# 640x480 @ 85 Hz, 43.27 kHz hsync

Modeline "640x480"     36     640  696  752  832   480  481  484  509 -HSync -VSync
# 800x600 @ 100 Hz, 64.02 kHz hsync
Modeline  "800x600"    69.65  800  864  928 1088   600  604  610  640 -HSync -VSync
# 800x600 @ 56 Hz, 35.15 kHz hsync
ModeLine "800x600"     36     800  824  896 1024   600  601  603  625
# 800x600 @ 60 Hz, 37.8 kHz hsync
Modeline "800x600"     40     800  840  968 1056   600  601  605  628 +hsync +vsync
# 800x600 @ 72 Hz, 48.0 kHz hsync
Modeline "800x600"     50     800  856  976 1040   600  637  643  666 +hsync +vsync
# 800x600 @ 85 Hz, 55.84 kHz hsync
Modeline  "800x600"    60.75  800  864  928 1088   600  616  621  657 -HSync -VSync

# 1024x480 for certain Vaios
Modeline "1024x480"   65 1024 1032 1176 1344 480 491 493 525 -HSync -VSync

# 1024x768 @ 100Hz, 80.21 kHz hsync
Modeline "1024x768"   115.5  1024 1056 1248 1440  768  771  781  802 -HSync -VSync
# 1024x768 @ 60 Hz, 48.4 kHz hsync
Modeline "1024x768"    65    1024 1032 1176 1344   768  771  777  806 -hsync -vsync
# 1024x768 @ 70 Hz, 56.5 kHz hsync
Modeline "1024x768"    75    1024 1048 1184 1328   768  771  777  806 -hsync -vsync
# 1024x768 @ 76 Hz, 62.5 kHz hsync
Modeline "1024x768"    85    1024 1032 1152 1360   768  784  787  823
# 1024x768 @ 85 Hz, 70.24 kHz hsync
Modeline "1024x768"   98.9  1024 1056 1216 1408   768 782 788 822 -HSync -VSync

# 1152x864 @ 100 Hz, 89.62 kHz hsync
Modeline "1152x864"   137.65 1152 1184 1312 1536   864  866  885  902 -HSync -VSync
# 1152x864 @ 60 Hz, 53.5 kHz hsync
Modeline  "1152x864"   89.9  1152 1216 1472 1680   864  868  876  892 -HSync -VSync
# 1152x864 @ 70 Hz, 62.4 kHz hsync
Modeline  "1152x864"   92    1152 1208 1368 1474   864  865  875  895
# 1152x864 @ 78 Hz, 70.8 kHz hsync
Modeline "1152x864"   110   1152 1240 1324 1552   864  864  876  908
# 1152x864 @ 84 Hz, 76.0 kHz hsync
Modeline "1152x864"   135    1152 1464 1592 1776   864  864  876  908

# 1280x960 @ 60 HzModeline "1280x960"   108   1280 1376 1488 1800 960 961 964 1000 +HSync +VSync
# 1280x960 @ 85 HzModeline "1280x960"   148.5 1280 1344 1504 1728 960 961 964 1011  +HSync +VSync

# 1280x1024 @ 100 Hz, 107.16 kHz hsync
Modeline "1280x1024"  181.75 1280 1312 1440 1696  1024 1031 1046 1072 -HSync -VSync
# 1280x1024 @ 61 Hz, 64.2 kHz hsync
Modeline "1280x1024"  110    1280 1328 1512 1712  1024 1025 1028 1054
# 1280x1024 @ 70 Hz, 74.59 kHz hsync
Modeline "1280x1024"  126.5 1280 1312 1472 1696  1024 1032 1040 1068 -HSync -VSync
# 1280x1024 @ 74 Hz, 78.85 kHz hsync
Modeline "1280x1024"  135    1280 1312 1456 1712  1024 1027 1030 1064
# 1280x1024 @ 76 Hz, 81.13 kHz hsync
Modeline "1280x1024"  135    1280 1312 1416 1664  1024 1027 1030 1064
# 1280x1024 @ 85 Hz, 91.15 kHz hsync
Modeline "1280x1024"  157.5  1280 1344 1504 1728  1024 1025 1028 1072 +HSync +VSync

# 1400x1050 @ 60Hz, 65.8 kHz hsync
Modeline "1400x1050"  129   1400 1464 1656 1960 1050 1051 1054 1100 +HSync +VSync
# 1400x1050 @ 70Hz, 76.8 kHz hsync
Modeline "1400x1050"  151   1400 1464 1656 1960 1050 1051 1054 1100 +HSync +VSync
# 1400x1050 @ 75Hz, 82.3 kHz hsync
Modeline "1400x1050"  162   1400 1464 1656 1960 1050 1051 1054 1100 +HSync +VSync
# 1400x1050 @ 85Hz, 93.2 kHz hsync
Modeline "1400x1050"  184   1400 1464 1656 1960 1050 1051 1054 1100 +HSync +VSync

# 1600x1200 @ 60Hz, 75.00 kHz hsync
Modeline "1600x1200"  162   1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +HSync +VSync
# 1600x1200 @ 70 Hz, 87.50 kHz hsync
Modeline "1600x1200"  189    1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 -HSync -VSync
# 1600x1200 @ 75 Hz, 93.75 kHz hsync
Modeline "1600x1200"  202.5  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +HSync +VSync
# 1600x1200 @ 85 Hz, 105.77 kHz hsync
Modeline "1600x1200"  220    1600 1616 1808 2080  1200 1204 1207 1244 +HSync +VSync

# 1800x1440 @ 64Hz, 96.15 kHz hsync 
ModeLine "1800X1440"  230    1800 1896 2088 2392 1440 1441 1444 1490 +HSync +VSync
# 1800x1440 @ 70Hz, 104.52 kHz hsync 
ModeLine "1800X1440"  250    1800 1896 2088 2392 1440 1441 1444 1490 +HSync +VSync

# Low-res Doublescan modes
# If your chipset does not support doublescan, you get a 'squashed'
# resolution like 320x400.

# 320x200 @ 70 Hz, 31.5 kHz hsync, 8:5 aspect ratio
Modeline "320x200"     12.588 320  336  384  400   200  204  205  225 Doublescan
# 320x240 @ 60 Hz, 31.5 kHz hsync, 4:3 aspect ratio
Modeline "320x240"     12.588 320  336  384  400   240  245  246  262 Doublescan
# 320x240 @ 72 Hz, 36.5 kHz hsync
Modeline "320x240"     15.750 320  336  384  400   240  244  246  262 Doublescan
# 400x300 @ 56 Hz, 35.2 kHz hsync, 4:3 aspect ratio
ModeLine "400x300"     18     400  416  448  512   300  301  302  312 Doublescan
# 400x300 @ 60 Hz, 37.8 kHz hsync
Modeline "400x300"     20     400  416  480  528   300  301  303  314 Doublescan
# 400x300 @ 72 Hz, 48.0 kHz hsync
Modeline "400x300"     25     400  424  488  520   300  319  322  333 Doublescan
# 480x300 @ 56 Hz, 35.2 kHz hsync, 8:5 aspect ratio
ModeLine "480x300"     21.656 480  496  536  616   300  301  302  312 Doublescan
# 480x300 @ 60 Hz, 37.8 kHz hsync
Modeline "480x300"     23.890 480  496  576  632   300  301  303  314 Doublescan
# 480x300 @ 63 Hz, 39.6 kHz hsync
Modeline "480x300"     25     480  496  576  632   300  301  303  314 Doublescan
# 480x300 @ 72 Hz, 48.0 kHz hsync
Modeline "480x300"     29.952 480  504  584  624   300  319  322  333 Doublescan

EndSection


# **********************************************************************
# Graphics device section
# **********************************************************************

# Any number of graphics device sections may be present

Section "Device"
    Identifier        "Generic VGA"
    VendorName        "Unknown"
    BoardName "Unknown"
    Chipset   "generic"

#    VideoRam 256

#    Clocks   25.2 28.3

EndSection

# Device configured by Xconfigurator:

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "XGA-1  (ISA bus)"
    VendorName  "Unknown"
    BoardName   "Unknown"
    #VideoRam    8192
    #Instance  7           # XGA instance 0-7
    #COPbase   0xC8F00     # XGA memory-mapped register address
    #POSbase   0           # Disable probing if above are specified
    # Insert Clocks lines here if appropriate
EndSection


# **********************************************************************
# Screen sections
# **********************************************************************

# The Colour SVGA server

Section "Screen"
    Driver      "svga"
    Device      "Generic VGA"
    #Device      "XGA-1  (ISA bus)"
    Monitor     "My Monitor"
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       8
        #Modes       "640x480"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
EndSection

# The 16-color VGA server

Section "Screen"
    Driver      "vga16"
    Device      "Generic VGA"
    Monitor     "My Monitor"
    Subsection "Display"
        Modes       "640x480" "800x600"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
EndSection

# The Mono server

Section "Screen"
    Driver      "vga2"
    Device      "Generic VGA"
    Monitor     "My Monitor"
    Subsection "Display"
        Modes       "640x480" "800x600"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
EndSection

# The accelerated servers (S3, Mach32, Mach8, 8514, P9000, AGX, W32, Mach64
# I128, and S3V)
Section "Screen"
    Driver      "accel"
    Device      "XGA-1  (ISA bus)"
    Monitor     "My Monitor"
    DefaultColorDepth   8
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       8
        Modes       "640x480"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
EndSection

#/* Framebuffer device */

Section "Screen"
    Driver "FBDev"
    Device "Generic VGA"
    Monitor "My Monitor"
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "default"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

grub.conf:

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/hda2
#          initrd /initrd-version.img
#boot=/dev/hda
default=0
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
title Red Hat Linux (2.4.7-10)
    root (hd0,0)
    #//kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.7-10 ro root=/dev/hda2
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.7-10 ro root=/dev/hda2 vga=773
    initrd /initrd-2.4.7-10.img
```

---

**Screenshots:**

Available VGA Modes (nb: only 8 bit modes are supported by XF86_FBDev):

[image]

Setup commands:

[image]

Bootup in framebuffer mode (displays Linux penguin top left):

[image]

startx:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post the full XF86Config?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I have attached `XF86Config` and `grub.conf` to the "Config files" section.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, then you can use Xming.

Prerequisites:

- Virtual Box 6.0 or lower (as 6.1 enforces hardware acceleration which may not be compatible with Red Hat 7.2 Enigma)
- Windows 7 host (192.168.1.97)
- Red Hat 7.2 (Enigma) guest (192.168.1.109)

Setup Xming:

1. Download and install Xming (Public Domain Release (as opposed to Website/Donor/Paid release)) (you can also get it from SourceForge)
2. Download and install Xming-fonts
3. Go to Start Menu -> Xming -> XLaunch -> One window -> Next -> Start no client -> Next -> No Access Control -> Next -> Finish

Setup Virtual Box:

1. Create a new virtual machine guest (eg. Name: "Redhat 7.2", Type: "Linux", Version: "Linux 2.4 (32-bit)", Memory Size: 128 mb, 5 gb disk)
2. Select "Redhat 7.2" virtual machine settings -> Network -> Adapter 1 -> Attached to: "Bridged Adapter" (as opposed to NAT)
3. Click Ok

Setup Red Hat 7.2 (Enigma):

1. Perform a Custom "Everything" installation on Virtual Box (ie. 2879 mb) (tick the "Skip X Configuration" option)
2. After installation is completed, login to root console
3. "ipchains -F" (to clear firewall rules)

Setup Putty:

1. Open Putty
2. Go to Connection -> SSH -> X11 -> Select "Enable X11 forwarding"
3. Go to Session -> Host Name (or IP address) -> 192.168.1.109
4. Click Open to connect to the Red Hat 7.2 server

Start GUI:

1. In Putty session, login as root
2. Type "export DISPLAY=192.168.1.97:0"
3. Type "gnome-session"

Gnome will start up in Xming.

---

Screenshots:

Guest version:

[image]

Export display and start GUI:

[image]

Gnome starts in Xming:

[image]